# Nginx : images not served in HTTPS

Tags: nginx, https

I have on my website an `admin/` subdirectory, which I'd like to be in HTTPS, so I tried the following configuration, based on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398514/nginx-https-when-only-matching-admin-subfolder) :

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name blob.tld;
    root /srv/www/blob;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location /blog/admin/* {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.php /index.html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name blob.tld;

    root /srv/www/blob/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    ssl_certificate /srv/www/blob.tld.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /srv/www/blob.tld.key;

    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location /blog/admin {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        try_files $uri $uri/index.php /index.html;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}
```

But then images in `admin/style/` are not served.

I looked at the log files, that say :

```
/var/log/nginx/access.log:
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Apr/2014:15:06:27 +0200] "GET /blog/admin/style/lock.png HTTP/1.1" 403 46 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0"

/var/log/nginx/error.log:
2014/04/25 15:06:27 [error] 23629#0: *404 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Access to the script '/srv/www/blob/blog/admin/style/lock.png' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: blob.tld, request: "GET /blog/admin/style/lock.png HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
```

Given the error.log file, I think the problem comes from the first location instruction in the HTTPS server (the difference with the HTTP one being `~ \.php$`). **So I tried to make the exact symetric** (with `\.php$` instructions in another `location` instruction) :

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    [...]

    location /blog/admin/* {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.php /index.html;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

But then… no HTTPS at all.

I still have the solution of letting images be served in HTTP, but that is kinda frustrating :

```
location  /blog/admin/style {
    return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

I have nginx 1.1.19 and php 5.3.10 with php-fpm.

Comment: Does [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/22036-how-can-i-get-apache-to-treat-image-files-as-php-files/) help?  Otherwise my hunch is you have the execute bit set on all images.

Comment: Take a look at this Q&A from SO and see if it solves your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9022102/ssl-for-subdirectoyr-within-nginx-server-configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reason why in the https section you send **everything** under /blog/admin to FastCGI? Why not make a rule specific to *.php like you have in the http section?

In other words, under http you have:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

but under https, you have:

```
location /blog/admin {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    try_files $uri $uri/index.php /index.html;
}
```

I think if you change **/blog/admin** to **~ /blog/admin/.*\.php$** your problem would be solved...

Comment: This **is** what I tried in a second part ("So I tried to make the exact symetric..."), but as I said, I have then no HTTPS at all : everything goes to HTTP. Modified my question to be a little bit clearer.

Comment: You are kinda right. Is it possible to validate my answer **and** give you the bounty ?

Comment: @Baronsed: wouldn't it be cleverer to add your solution into the answer Rouben wrote up, since the only difference is that your solution implements this answer's suggestions?